# Make a UIBarButtonItem's text bold

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I want to make my bar button item text in a toolbar (or Nav bar) bold. I know how to change the font color manually with an NSAttributedString like below:

```
button.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 133/255, blue: 94/255, alpha: 1.0)], for: .normal)
```

I also know how to change bold on something else like a tableview cell with `UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)`, but this can't be used with the above.

Is there a simple way to set a UIBarButtonItem bold?

*Edit: other similar answered questions show just changing the font type to Helvetica-Bold using `NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 12.0)`, but is there a way to have the actual system font bolded, or is Helvetica-Bold the exact equivalent of the system font bolded?

Answer (score -3):

i think it's help you

```
    extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    @discardableResult func bold(_ text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont(name: ""AmericanTypewriter-Bold"", size: 12)!]
        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text, attributes: attrs)
        append(boldString)

        return self
    }

    @discardableResult func normal(_ text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let normal = NSAttributedString(string: text)
        append(normal)

        return self
    }
}
```

and use like below

```
    let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
formattedString
    .bold("Bold Text")

button.setTitle(formattedString, for: .normal)
```

Comment: The question is about `UIBarButtonItem`, not `UIButton`.

Comment: So the font must be set to Helvetica-Bold? The system font itself can't just be bolded?

Comment: actually am give you a sample not a solution please try your code in this way

Comment: @AdamS yes change the font name which font bold attribute you want

Comment: i think Helvetica-Bold is default system bold font